# RGL ellipse3d transparency problem when using bgplot3d

Tags: r, rgl

My goal is to display points on a transparent sphere using RGL. This works fine by using

```
open3d(windowRect=c(0,0,512,512))
plot3d(c(x,-x),c(y,-y),c(z,z),aspect=F)
shade3d(ellipse3d(diag(3), c(0,0,0),t=1),
        color='lightgray',alpha=0.8,lit=FALSE, add=TRUE)
rglwidget()
```

[image: sphere with points correctly]

However, when in the same plot the function `bgplot3d()` is called, the sphere is somehow pushed into the foreground and drowns out all the points and the box around it:

[image: sphere with points drowned]

It would be great to have the sphere in the same way as before, even in the case `bgplot3d()` has been called. I already experimented with depth_mask, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: I don't see this.  What version of `rgl` are you using?  Exactly what code did you use for the bad plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has vanished after installing the most recent `rgl` update (version 0.109.2).

Comment: You should at least state what version you were using before that had the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Call `plot3d` after `shade3d`:

```
library(rgl)

set.seed(666)
pts <- uniformly::runif_on_sphere(25, d = 3)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)

open3d(windowRect = c(50, 50, 562, 562))
shade3d(ellipse3d(diag(3), t = 1),
        color = 'lightgray', alpha = 0.8, lit = FALSE)
plot3d(pts, aspect = FALSE, add = TRUE, col = "red", size = 4)
bgplot3d(plot(x, y))
```

Comment: The same effect happens for me, using this order. Are the points visible on the sphere for you?

Comment: Yes, I see the red points.

Comment: With the standard settings for depth testing, the order of drawing should hardly matter.  (The exception is when things are drawn at the exact same location, then the order matters.)  With your data that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the hint. Updating rgl has solved my problem.